# Some users are missing from `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=substringof`

Tags: listdata.svc

In a medium sized sharepoint server farm I have about 3 separate domains that are in use.

I often need to use Sharepoint web service to list a User's profile:

`/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=` using the following filter `substringof('DOMAIN\USERNAME',toupper(Account)) eq true`

That works with the exception that for some reason I'm missing some of the users from this search. This search only returns some of the users from each domain.

Why do you think this might be happening? Is this a security thing about the user account I'm trying to call the listdata.svc with?

Comment: Ensure that user has logged in to the site atleast once. Whenever user logs on to the site , during first login entry is made to the site info list

Comment: Interesting! I will double check.

Comment: definitely have logged in. same issue.

Comment: First thought; list (check yourself) the names that do and don't work..  my first inclination is that its a (sub)string issue

Comment: we can clearly find some users, and cannot find the others using valid substring matches

Comment: Was this resolved?